# How do you set Style Height, Top and Left in IE 11 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, height, internet-explorer-11

The following code is NOT setting the style HEIGHT, LEFT and TOP correctly in IE11. Works in IE8. The values (HEIGHT, LEFT and TOP) are correct in the code in the CreateWindow function.

In IE8 this is the (correct) output:

```
    <table width="1302" id="window_1" style="height: 558px; position: absolute; left: 300px; z-index: 1; top: 99px border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
```

In IE11 this is the (incorrect) output. Note height, left and top are all 0:

```
        <table width="1302" id="window_1" style="height: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; z-index: 1; top: 0px border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
```

JavaScript Functions

```
    function createWindow(intRecordID, url, x, y, width, height, isLinkingEnabled, parentWindowID, intRecordID_DesktopWindow_Parent, headerField, detailField) {
    //create the desktopWindow
    var desktop = new desktopWindow(isLinkingEnabled);
    //set the intRecordID
    desktop.intRecordID = intRecordID;
    //add the window to the array of windows
    desktopWindows[desktop.id] = desktop;
    desktop.windowChanged = function() {};

    if(intRecordID > 0) desktop.saveMenu.content.innerHTML = desktop.saveMenu.content.innerHTML.replace(WINDOW_BUTTON_SAVE, WINDOW_BUTTON_SAVE_ACTIVE);

    if(parentWindowID >= 0) desktop.parentWindowID = parentWindowID;
    //set up the window's parent window's intRecordID
    desktop.intRecordID_DesktopWindow_Parent = intRecordID_DesktopWindow_Parent;
    if(headerField != undefined) desktop.headerField = headerField;
    if(detailField != undefined) desktop.detailField = detailField;
    linkAllBrokenLinkedWindows();
    //set up the window
    desktop.table.style.zIndex = ++currentMaxZIndex;
    //alert(x+", "+y+", "+width+", "+height)
    //alert(currentMaxZIndex);
    if(intRecordID > 0) 
    {
        desktop.setCoordinates(x, y);
    } 
    else if(x > 334 || y < 85) 
    {
        desktop.setCoordinates(x, y);
    } 
    else if (desktop.id > 10)
    {
        var desktopwindowstart = Math.floor(desktop.id / 10);
        var desktopwindowstop = (desktop.id / 10);
        var desktopwindowvalue = Math.round((desktopwindowstop - desktopwindowstart) * 10)
        /*alert(desktopwindowstop)
        alert(desktopwindowstart)
        alert(desktopwindowvalue)
        alert(desktop.id)*/
        //desktop.setCoordinates(x+((desktopwindowstart - 10)*20), y+((desktopwindowstart - 10)*20));
        desktop.setCoordinates(x+((desktopwindowvalue)*20), y+((desktopwindowvalue)*20));
    }
    else if (desktop.id > 2 && desktop.id < 11)
    {
        desktop.setCoordinates(x+((desktop.id - 2)*20), y+((desktop.id - 2)*20));
    }
    else if (desktop.id < 3)
    {
        desktop.setCoordinates(x, y);
    }
    /*
     * Call this twice because when the window is first initialized it does not have a
     * size by which to grab the offset, so on the second call there is an valid offset
     * that can be grabbed so that the window can be drawn the correct size.
     */
    //desktop.setDimensions(width, height);
    desktop.setDimensions(width, height);
    //alert(document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.hostname + url)
    //CODE CHANGED - Changed to use a regular url
    if(left(url,4) == 'http') {
        desktop.iframe.src = url;
    } else {
        desktop.iframe.src = window.document.location.protocol + "//" + window.document.location.hostname + url;
    }
    //End Changed 04012013
    //alert(url);
    //alert(desktop.iframe.src);
    //alert(windowChanged);
    desktop.windowChanged = windowChanged;
    /*
     * Return the newly created desktop just in case it is needed by the calling function
     */
    //CODE ADDED 05272015 - Added to try to make the windows movable with a method that will work in IE9
    /*$('#window_'+desktop.id).draggable({
        cursor: 'move',        // sets the cursor apperance
        stack: $('#window_'+desktop.id)       // brings the form to front
    });*/
    //End Added 05272015
    return desktop;
}

    //Function to get Window Coordinates
function setCoordinates(x, y) {
    //alert("setCoordinates="+x+" "+y);
    if(typeof x != 'undefined') {
        if(x <= 0) x = 0;
        //this.table.style.setAttribute('left', x);
        //this.table.left = x;
        this.table.style.left = x;
        //$(this).css("left", x);
    }
    if(typeof y != 'undefined') {
        if(y <= 0) y = 0;
        //this.table.style.setAttribute('top', y);
        this.table.style.top = y;
        //$(this).css("top", y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with IE11, but you can always set the browser back to older standards:

```
<head>
  <!-- Use Internet Explorer 8 Standards mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
</head>
```

Comment: That is the current approach I have been using. No longer want to do that for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. You piqued my curiosity, and I've been digging around the internet. Seems to be a fairly common problem without a great solution....